# How to save images in sql server using winform?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

i am trying to save images like bmp,jpg,gif & png into sql server database. but not able to save all the formats into database. Only png image is getting saved into database. if trying to save jpeg, .bmp & .gif images, it's showing error "A generic error occured in GDI+". What is the problem?

```
private void InitializeOpenFileDialog()
{
 try
    {
      this.openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

       // Set the file dialog to filter for graphics files. 
       this.openFileDialog1.Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*";
       //"image files|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;.*;";
       // Allow the user to select multiple images. 
       this.openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
       this.openFileDialog1.Title = "My Image Browser";
      }
  catch(Exception es){
       MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
                   }

  }

//load picture
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {             

         try
          {
           MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();

           pictureBox2.Image.Save(ms1, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
           // byte[] img_arr1 = ms1.ToArray();
          byte[] img_arr1 = new byte[ms1.Length];
          ms1.Read(img_arr1, 0, img_arr1.Length);
          SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"data source=xdfgh\ALEXDAVE;database=x1234;UID=sa;password=x67890");
          con.Open();
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into myTable(enrolmentno,aadhaarno,name,fname,address,dob,gender,picimage)values(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h)", con);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", enrolmentno_txt.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", aadhaarno_txt.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", name_txt.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", fname_txt.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", address_txt.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", dateTimePicker1.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", gender);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", img_arr1);
          int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          if (result > 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Data inserted successfully");
          else
            MessageBox.Show("Data is not inserted in database");
          con.Close();                
            }
            catch(Exception es){
            MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
            }
}

        }

private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Activate();
            string[] files = openFileDialog1.FileNames;

            try
            {
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
                    FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();
                    pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(fileStream);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    fileStream.Close();

                }
            }
                //es
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please select only image files.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: where did the image in the picbox come from (how did it get there)...indeed, is there an image there?

Comment: image loads from openFileDialog1

Comment: Do you get the exception on the Image.Save line?

Comment: @MarkPM it's fine with Image.Save line but not executed to the next line. immediately moving to exception.

Comment: Aside:  a good bit of advice is to be very sure that you need to store images in the first place.  Not good practice, IMO.  Been there, done that.  Store files, and only links to those files in your database, whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the the image is valid?
What line are you getting the error on?
Like the error indicates, it's a GDI error, and not a SQL Error.

You can remove the need for GDI by replacing the following lines of code

```
MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox2.Image.Save(ms1, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] img_arr1 = new byte[ms1.Length];
ms1.Read(img_arr1, 0, img_arr1.Length);
```

with this

```
byte[] img_arr1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

where fileName is the file that was selected

Comment: i am not using single image to get error. it's accepting png images only. how to mention fileName in the code?

Comment: fileName is the path of the file that was selected in openFileDialog1

Comment: you have to remove the 4 lines of code above... they must not execute. It's impossible to get a GDI error with File.ReadAllBytes

Comment: what problem? Please update your question with your current code and error

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes can't cause a GDI error. I don't think you've uncommented the 4 lines of code above. Or your error is caused by something else

Comment: now pls chk edited code openFileDialog1_FileOk(). is it any wrong with this. i commented the 4 lines also.